# Calculate the months between 2 dates C#

Tags: c#, date

What is the best way to calculate the months between 2 dates. I dont need the number but the actual months.

What is the best way to accomplish.

```
Given 2 dates May 1 2008 and August 3 2008 , I should get May , June , July, August.
or 

Nov 1st 2009 and April 3rd 2010 ==> Nov ,Dec, Jan ,Feb , Mar,April .
```

Comment: You don't need a number? So what you need? List of months in between? Give some examples.

Comment: I think perhaps he's looking for, if someone provides June 17th, 2006 and August 23rd, 2006, then it outputs "June, July, August"?

Comment: Yes @sean is correct.

Comment: What if the dates were reverse? Would you want the reponse reversed? For example "August 23rd, 2006" and "June 17th, 2006" would output "August, July, June". Or it goes more than 1 year?

Comment: I am assuming the dates to be min to max.

Comment: @Greens You should include a sample output in the question so that it's clearer that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Give an example for your input and what the expected output should be.  Your requirements are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To account for years:

```
 DateTime one =  new DateTime(2006, 06, 16),  two = new DateTime(2007, 08, 23);
 if (two > one)
 {
     int firstMonth = one.Month;
     int secondMonth = two.Month + 12 * (two.Year - one.Year);

     var months = new List<string>();
     for (int i = firstMonth; i <= secondMonth; i++)
     {
        months.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((i -1) % 12 + 1));
     }
  }
```

Pretty trivial to build the case for reversing it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2009, 11, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 4, 1);

for(var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddMonths(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMM",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```